# How can I fix image cutoff problem in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have set various images as featured images but the images get cut off, how can I achieve showing the entire image?

Here is my website https://www.herbalcity.co/

[Images getting cut-off example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvy8.jpg)

I have used the following css:

```css
.preloader .full-width {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.full-width {

    min-width: 100%;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    color: transparent;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: auto;
    image-rendering: auto;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Comment: Could you share a link to your site where the issue occurs?

Comment: I have added it now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit` to scale the image down so it is always completely visible. Some reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```
.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still unable to fix the problem. I may miss something. can you please figure me out? Here is my website. https://www.herbalcity.co

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.
The problem can't be fixed with CSS because CDN cut the image off before display, so CSS won't help.

I'm now using different layout from another plugin, and it works now.